# Efficient way to add sample information as new column to data set

Tags: r, random, tidyverse

I know how I can subset a data frame by sampling certain rows. However, I'm struggling with finding an easy (preferably tidyverse) way to just ADD the sampling information as a new column to my data set, i.e. I simply want to populate a new column with "1" if it is sampled and "0" if not.

I currently have this one, but it feels overly complicated. Note, in the example I want to sample 3 rows per group.

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1),
                 var   = 1:15)

library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(sampling_info = sample.int(n(), size = n(), replace = FALSE),
         sampling_info = if_else(sampling_info <= 3, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(sampling_info = as.integer(row_number() %in% sample(n(), size = 3))) %>%
  ungroup
         
#   group   var sampling_info
#   <dbl> <int>         <int>
# 1     1     1             0
# 2     1     3             0
# 3     1     5             1
# 4     1     6             0
# 5     1     7             0
# 6     1     8             0
# 7     1    14             1
# 8     1    15             1
# 9     2     2             0
#10     2     4             1
#11     2     9             1
#12     2    10             0
#13     2    11             0
#14     2    12             1
#15     2    13             0
```

`sample(n(), size = 3)` will generate 3 random row numbers for each `group` and we assign 1 for those row numbers.